# Remove usernames in a file and replace with a incremental number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

This is a text processing question. I have 2 files:

```
joeblogs
johnsmith
chriscomp
```

```
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" joeblogs@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" joeblogs@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" johnsmith@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" joeblogs@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" chriscomp@hostname
```

File 1 contains a list of unique usernames that appear in a log (file 2).

Desired output

```
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER2@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER3@hostname
```

I guess I don't need both files. File 1 is generated by parsing file 2 for the unique usernames. My logic was to get a list of usernames that I know appear in file 2, and loop through it, replacing with `sed`.

Something like:

```
for i in $(cat file1);do sed -e 's/$i/USER[X]';done
```

Where `USER[X]` increments with each unique username.

However I can't do this. I don't even think that logic is sound. Can I have help to achieve the desired output? `awk`/`sed`/`grep`/`bash` are all welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have realized that you *"don't need the 2 files"*, use the following **`awk`** solution to process the initial *log* file in one pass:

```
awk '{
         u_name = substr($5, 1, index($5, "@"));
         if (!(u_name in users)) users[u_name] = ++c;
         sub(/^[^@]+/, "USER" users[u_name], $5)
     }1' file.log
```

The output:

```
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER2@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER3@hostname
```

Answer (score 6):

Another awk

```
awk '!($5 in a){a[$5]=++i}{sub("[^@]*","USER"a[$5],$5)}1' infile
```

Answer (score 5):

With bash you could do:

```
n=0
declare -A users=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ([^[:blank:]]+)@ ]]; then
        user=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        if [[ -z ${users[$user]} ]]; then
            users[$user]=USER$((++n))
        fi
        line=${line/$user/${users[$user]}}
    fi 
    echo "$line"
done < File2
```

or a perl one-liner

```
perl -pe 's/(\S+)(?=@)/ $users{$1} ||= "USER".++$n /e' File2
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you could do this:

```bash
$ sed "$(sed '=' File1 | sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/s%\2@hostname%USER\1@hostname%/')" File2
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER2@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER1@hostname
12:00:00 (AAA) OUT: "string" USER3@hostname
$
```

There are 3 `sed` commands here.  `sed` commands 2 and 3 generate a sed expression out of File1 that is in turn used by command 1 to process File2:

- Command 2 simply appends the line number after each line of File1
- Command 3 rearranges each line of File1 and its following line number into a `sed` expression to replace e.g. `joeblogs@hostname` with `USER1@hostname`, and so on for all the users in File1
- Command 1 then uses the generated `sed` expression to process the all the replacements in File2.